# Sharepoint 2013 file copy

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, csom

I have a requirement.when a file is uploaded to document library,if a PDF file is uploaded then it should be routed to another Site collection’s library.with the help of OOTB or workflows or rest calls or CSOM.
Please let me know if any body worked on this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one event receiver, so when an item is added in a list you can check its extension.If it is a pdf file then you can write a code to copy that file to the desired location in another site collection and after successful copy ,you can delete that file.

Comment: I am not allowed to create a event receiver.. as I need to use only workflows.

Comment: In that case you can visit this link and it may help you. Thanks 
http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/sharepoint-designer-workflow-move-document-one-library-next.htm